# Avalonia UI Carousel Example

Tags: xaml, .net-core, carousel, avaloniaui

I'm rather new to Avalonia UI / XAML / .NET MVVM in general. While I really like Avalonia so far, it's still in beta and lacks extensive documentation. Hence I sometimes struggle to get specific things working or finding out how I should use them correctly.
Could somebody point me to an example using the Carousel control? Which properties should I set in the xaml, what kind of item list should be behind it etc?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find usage example in ControlCatalog project from the main repository:

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/CarouselPage.xaml

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/CarouselPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Thanks - those samples are indeed very helpful. However how would I go about setting the Image subcontrols of the Carousel programmatically in an MVVM way? I know how to bind the fixed Image sources, but what if I want to dynamically add/remove images from the carousel?

Comment: `Carousel` is an `ItemsControl`, so you can use `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` properties.